# trouble with graph edge representation

Tags: algorithm, user-input, graph-theory, ford-fulkerson

I'm pursuing an algorithms course and currently we're learning network flow algorithms and hence naturally, we'll be dealing with graphs.

The issue I'm facing is with an assignment question that we've recieved, where we're supposed to implement the ford-fulkerson algorithm.
The input parameters seem very bizzare for creating the graph to perform the algorithm on-
for instance, here is a sample input test case

{Here, N is the number of vertices and M is the number of edges}

```
N = 5, M =  4
Starting vertex = 1
Ending vertex = 5
Edges[]= {{1,2,1},{3,2,2},{4,2,3},{2,5,5}}
```

It is the last line that confuses me. What representation of a weighted graph exactly is this? I've tried looking this up online but everyone just uses adjacency matrices.

As I've mentioned, I'm not able to understand how we go about inputting a graph here with this bizarre input format.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would guess the triplets on the last line are (u, v, w) where u and v are vertices and w is the weight of edge (u, v). Note that the choice of curly brackets `{ }` is terrible, since curly brackets typically denote sets in mathematics, and unordered data structures in many programming languages; but here {4, 2, 3} would be very different from {2, 3, 4} and {4, 3, 2}.

Comment: Stef is correct.  Please fix your tags - this is a graph-theory question, not a graph.  Please read tag description before adding a tag.

Comment: You should complain to the person who assigned this.  Giving input with no documentation of the input is what is bizarre here.